# Unable to use parameter in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to select a certain number of records from an Access table using VB.Net, however I'm having trouble setting the parameters. The code is listed below:

```
Dim sqlQry As String
Dim iNumber As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtNoMemberships.Text)

sqlQry = "SELECT TOP @MemberNo [ID] FROM tblMembership WHERE [Taken] IS NULL"

Dim objConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Try
    objConn.ConnectionString = dbConnection
    objConn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = objConn
    cmd.CommandText = sqlQry
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberNo", iNumber)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

If I change `sqlQry` to something like "SELECT 5 [ID] FROM tblMembership WHERE [Taken] IS NULL" then the command runs fine and I get no debug. But if I try to use parameters, I get the error:

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

I know I could get away with it doing the following, but i thought it's best to err on the side of caution due to SQL injection:

```
sqlQry = "SELECT TOP " & iNumber & " [ID] FROM tblMembership WHERE [Taken] IS NULL"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HardCode already said I think too it's not possible to use a parameter for the TOP N clause of the SELECT command.
So, why not to concatenate the string to not use the parameter?

```
sqlQry = "SELECT TOP " & Convert.ToInt32(txtNoMemberships.Text).ToString() & " [ID] FROM tblMembership WHERE [Taken] IS NULL"
```

SQL Injection is not an issue as we're converting txtNoMembership to an Int32 then back to a String (remember to never concatenate strings without any cure on them first!)

Comment: Henrik, good point on the converting, this eleviates the risk of sql injection! Ive amended my code to this format and viola all is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use brackets:

```
sqlQry = "SELECT TOP (@MemberNo) [ID] FROM tblMembership WHERE [Taken] IS NULL"
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8f51e321db075c2e9d2e79fe9533129d)**

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work, as others have later said i dont think you can put a parameter as an expression. Thanks though, it made another bit of my code work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
Dim sqlQry As String
Dim iNumber As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtNoMemberships.Text)

sqlQry = "SELECT TOP " & iNumber.ToString()  & " [ID] FROM tblMembership WHERE [Taken] IS NULL"

Dim objConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Try
    objConn.ConnectionString = dbConnection
    objConn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = objConn
    cmd.CommandText = sqlQry
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```